# How to handle multiple custom "Catch" error messages in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, try-catch

I have 3 commands inside of a Try and I want custom Catch error messages for each of them in case of an error

e.g. If the first will fail then I would like to get the following message: "Error creating a directory!"

If the second will fail then: "Copy items failed"

If the third will fail then: "Content is not created"

How can I apply that?

```
    Try{

        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Name "Script" -Path "C:\Temp\" -Force

        Copy-Item -Path $FilePath_ps1 -Destination C:\temp\script -Force

        Set-Content -Value "test" -Path "C:\Temp\Script\test.txt" -Force
    
    }
    Catch{
        " what code do I need here?"
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Set a message variable before each action, e. g. `$errorMsg = 'Error creating a directory; New-Item ...` and use that in the `catch` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer zett42 gave is correct. Here is how you would implement it in your solution:

```
$errorAction = "STOP"
Try{
    $errorMsg = "New-Item failed"
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Name "Script" -Path "C:\Temp\" -Force -ErrorAction $errorAction
    $errorMsg = "Copy-Item failed"
    Copy-Item -Path $FilePath_ps1 -Destination C:\temp\script -Force -ErrorAction $errorAction
    $errorMsg = "Set-Content failed"
    Set-Content -Value "test" -Path "C:\Temp\Script\test.txt" -Force -ErrorAction $errorAction
}Catch{
    $errorMsg + " with error: $_"
}
```

The output would be for instance:

> Copy-Item failed with error: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path'
> because it is null.

I have added the ErrorAction to make sure it stops on every error right after the execution.